# How to get multiple values from picker in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

this is my code for react-native picker.
I want to get all values for that json array which is selected.

I want to provide multiple select.

```
<Picker
                  mode="dropdown"
                  style={styles.droplist}
                  selectedValue={this.state.mode}
                  onValueChange={this.funcValueChanged}>
                  <Picker.Item label="Select Company" value="Select Company" />
                  {
                    this.state.data.map((item, key) => (
                      <Picker.Item
                        label={item.Co_Name + ' (' + item.CompCode + ')'}
                        value={key}
                        key={key}
                      />
                    )))
                  }
                </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for single/multiple selection

import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

```
         <DropDownPicker
            items={getAllStates}
            searchable={true}
            searchablePlaceholder="Search for an item"
            searchablePlaceholderTextColor="gray"
            placeholder="Select States"
            placeholderTextColor={"grey"}
            multiple={true}
            multipleText="%d items have been selected."
            containerStyle={{ marginTop: 8, marginBottom: 8, width: 
            "92%", alignSelf: "center", }}
            onChangeItem={item => {

            }
            } />
```

Comment: is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this lightweight and completely customizable package [rn-multipicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-multipicker)

Full article: https://dev.to/rahull04/add-multi-select-dropdown-to-react-native-applications-53ef

```
import { RNMultiSelect } from 'rn-multipicker';

const COUNTRIES = [
"Afghanistan",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
"American Samoa",
"Andorra",
"Angola",
"Anguilla",
"Antarctica",
"Antigua and Barbuda",
"Argentina",
];

const App() {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState<string[]>([]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <RNMultiSelect placeholder="Countries" data={COUNTRIES} onSelectedItemsChange={(value) => setSelectedItems(value)} selectedItems={selectedItems} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Linkedin Post](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7150528727720820736?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)

Answer (score 0):

The package used here is @react-native-picker/picker which does not support the multi-selected.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues/250)

Use `npm i react-native-multiple-select` instead.